# X86-16 writing ASCIIZ strings directly to video

Tags: assembly

While developing my OS, I decided there was a need to be more verbose about what was happening in real-mode. The idea of embedding non-printable characters in an ASCII string was born from knowledge of VT100 control codes, but I wanted to make it a little simpler and more comprehensive in functionality at the same time.

On a Win7 machine, Notepad++ and NASM 2.11.08 are used to create binaries. Whenever possible, DOSBOX and DEBUG or DEBUGX are used for testing code, which is ultimately copied to image for BOCH's and finally to bootable media.

My code is completely independent and not intended to conform to any particular ABI or interface with established libraries. Any conformity to CDECL or FASTCALL is purely coincidental as I pick and choose what serves the purpose.

---

At either command prompt or in DEBUG, this allows testing of each string and waiting for user input after each display. I've selected 1000:0 because code can be modified, reloaded and jump back and forth from command prompt without affecting string to be displayed.

```
    BDA     equ     40H

    VIDEO       equ     10H
      SAP       equ     05H         ; BIOS function, change displayed page
 KEYBOARD       equ     16H

            org     0x100           ; Origin for DOS .com files

; =============================================================================================
;   This benchmark will display or at least process successive NULL terminated strings, wait
;   for user response and then continue unless beginning of next string is NULL.
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            enter   8, 0            ; So stack will be page aligned entering ShowS.

    ; As ShowS is an integral part of real mode startup code in my OS, DOSBOX is used as
    ; a convenient means of testing code, so this mimics required functionality.

            push    0x1000          ; Segment where ASCIIZ string lives
            push    0               ; Offset from segment

    Read:   call    ShowS           ; SP = FFE0
            jz      .done           ; ZF = 1 if byte pointed to by SI is NULL.

            push    ax              ; This is the pointer to next string.

            xor     ax, ax          ; This allows me to single step through each string
            int     KEYBOARD
            cmp     al, ESC         ; Did operator press escape?
            jnz     Read

    .done:  leave                   ; Kill procedure frame so RET will go to proper place
            ret                     ; Essentially does an INT 20H @ CS:0000
```

> Frame sizes and stack alignment are only used to facilitate visualization in DEBUG.

---

```
; ____________________________________________________________________________________________

     Params:    dw      0           ; Offset into page in bytes
            db      0           ; Page to write too (0 - 7)
            db      0           ; Characters attribute

  %define   TxtPntr BP + 4      ; ARG0 = Far pointer to ASCIIZ string.
  %define   SafeStk BP - (FrmSize +  7 * 2)

    Cursors     equ     50H     ; Base of array of WORDS for cursor postion of each page.
      DispPg        equ     62H     ; Page currently being displayed
              EOS       equ       0H        ; End Of String
    FrmSize     equ       4H        ; Bytes reserved for local data

            ESC     equ       0H            
; =============================================================================================
;   Display ASCIIZ text on an 80 x 25 x 16 color console. This can be a single or an array
;   of strings, but must be terminated with DOUBLE NULL.

;   ENTER:  ARG1 = Segment portion of far pointer to string
;           ARG0 = Offset and ultimately loaded into DS:SI

;   LEAVE:    AX = Offset to next string (Only if ZF = 0)
;             CX = -1 if there was a buffer overrun (string larger than 128 bytes)
;             DX = Size of memory leak on stack in bytes

;   FLAGS:    ZF = 1 if at end of array of strings, otherwise there is another string.
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ShowS:  enter   FrmSize, 0          ; ARGS begin @ SS:FFF0

    ; NOTE: Any changes in this prologue must be representative in SafeStk definition.

            push    es                  ; 1
            push    ds                  ; 2
            push    di                  ; 3
            push    si                  ; 4
            push    fs                  ; 5

            push    BDA
            pop     fs                  ; Establish segment into BDA

            push    cs                  ; As it is a far call into this procedure, DS might
            pop     ds                  ; not be pointing to CS
            mov     si, Params          ; DS:SI points to the two DWORD parameters

            push    ds                  ; 6
            push    si                  ; 7  SafeStk points here

    ; At each iteration it is assumed to continue from last position in same page. To 
    ; override this, use whatever control characters at beginning of string to achieve desired
    ; results.

        ; In all probability, writes will be to the same page as previous, but for the sake
        ; of 12 bytes of code, this is as practical as conditionals to check BDA (active page)

            lodsw                       ; Get 16 bit offset into desired page.
            mov     di, ax
            lodsw                       ; AH = Attribute, AL = Page #
            push    ax
            add     al, 0B8H                ; Segments being @ 80x25 16 color
            shl     ax, 8
            mov     es, ax              ; ES:DI setup for STOSB or STOSW
            pop     ax                  ; Retrieve AH = characters attribute

            lds     si, [TxtPntr]       ; Grab far pointer to ASCIIZ string
            mov     cx, 128             ; Overflow count

    .next:  lodsb                       ; Read next or first char
            cmp     al, EOS
            jz      .done
            cmp     al, ' '
            jb      DoCtl               ; Execute handler for control character

; Write character to next location pointed to by ES:DI

    .post:  or      ah, ah              ; Has an attribute been defined
            jnz     .attr
            stosb
            inc     di
            jmp     .attr + 1           ; Do overrun check

    .attr:  stosw
            dec     cx                  ; Decrement displayable character count.
            jnc     .next               ; Return CX = -1 for overflow

    ; Until algorithm has been proven, this will give an indication of stack corruption.

    .done:  mov     dx, sp
            lea     sp, [SafeStk]       ; Changes in prologue affects this
            sub     dx, sp
            neg     dx                  ; CX = Difference in pointers

            shr     ax, 8               ; Move characters attribute into low nibble
            push    ax
            push    es
            mov     ax, di              ; Save copy of offset
            les     di, [SafeStk]
            stosw                       ; Save location of next write

    ; Skewing SP by one, forces attribute back into AH & MSB of video segment into AL

            inc     sp
            pop     ax
            inc     sp
            and     al, 7               ; Converts MSB of segment into page # (0-7)
            stosw
            add     sp, 4               ; Waste far pointer to procedures parameters

    ; Test character after this strings terminator to set ZF appropriately.

            test    byte [si], 0FFH     ; Test if there is another string.
            mov     ax, si              ; Return offset to next string in AX

            pop     fs
            pop     si
            pop     di
            pop     ds
            pop     es

            leave                       ; Kill procedure frame
            ret     2                   ; Only waste far pointers offset

    ; To avoid conditional jump of more than 128 bytes, this allows ret to branch back
    ; to DoCtl from a place than will definitely be more than 128 bytes away. It also serves
    ; as a convenient entry point for things that apply to each handler such as preserving AX

    DoCtl:  push    ax                  ; Need to preserve attribute
            push    .done               ; Set to return address
            jmp     .exe                ; First function in list
    .done:  pop     ax
            jmp     ShowS.next          ; Continue reading string

    ; Handlers should start here, but if not, suitable code should be implemented

        .exe:
```